# Opposing currents in a Ciruit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, power

If I have two currents flowing in opposite directions in a wire where both currents are equal magnitude and their is a bulb on the same wire does the bulb light up at all or is it bright/dim ?

Comment: Is this a question about mesh analysis?

Comment: I think its more relevant to loop analysis and  Kirchhoff’s voltage law

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis

Comment: Sorry but this hasn't cleared up my problem at all I saw this before I asked this question

Comment: On what basis do you distinguish two currents, in one wire?  A current meter won't see two values when connected.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a *linear* electrical circuit with two or more sources, we can always 'decompose' the current through a wire into 'component' currents due to each source; this is the [superposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_theorem).

*However*, since the brightness of the bulb depends on the *power* delivered, and since power is quadratic in the voltage or current for a resistive element (such as a light bulb to first approximation), we must first *sum* the component currents before determining the power delivered to the bulb.

Thus, if there are two component currents through the bulb, which are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction, the sum of the current components is zero and so the power delivered to the bulb is proportional to zero squared which is zero, i.e., the bulb will not light.

$$P_\mathrm{bulb} = R_\mathrm{bulb}\cdot (I_1 + I_2)^2 = R_\mathrm{bulb}\cdot \left(I_1 + (-I_1)\right)^2 = 0 \ne R_\mathrm{bulb}\cdot (I_1^2 + (-I_1)^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any common physical scenario where it makes sense to say "I have two currents flowing in opposite directions in a wire".

In [mesh analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis) we may say the current through a particular wire is the sum of two circulating mesh currents. But we mean the current through that wire is just a single value, determined by summing two values. We don't mean there are actually two different currents flowing in that wire.

So a lamp in a wire only experiences one current, even if we calculate that current by summing two other currents.

In mesh (or loop) analysis, if we determine the current through a lamp is 0, because it is the sum of two equal but oppositely signed mesh currents, then the lamp will not light.

(For a more physicsy explanation, consider, what is the power being consumed by a resistive circuit element with 0 net current through it?)